# How to find the cache location for AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager, secretsmanager

I am using parameter store for storing the database credentials, and accessing them using a talend job. However, due to multiple jobs accessing these parameters at the same time; we are facing issue to scale the parameter store, as it reached threshold.

I have decided to go with the AWS Secrets Manager, and so far I am able to successfully create/fetch these secrets using an AWS Lambda function (Python); and I am using Python client side caching library `SecretCache` and `SecretCacheConfig`.

Had the below queries regarding the same:

1. Is it possible to know the location where my lambda function is caching these secrets?
2. If the secrets changes while my talend job is executing, how to make sure that the talend job uses the updated value for a secret?
3. How to make sure that the latest value for a secret is being used.

Comment: the cache location is in memory

Answer (score 2):

The SecretCache implementation is an in-memory only cache so you will not be able to find the cache on disk anywhere.

Questions ii) and iii) are somewhat related and depend on how the secret is used. In order to have a [highly available rotation strategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html) you must be able to have two active secrets or users and alternate between them. By ensuring the cache is refreshed at more than twice the rotation rate, the cache will switch to the latest user password before the current one is over-written.

For example, if you are using a database, you could setup [multi-user rotation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html) and rotate once a day. Since the default cache refresh rate ([secret_refresh_interval](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-python)) is 1 hour, the cache will pick up the latest version of the secret before the next rotation.

Comment: Thanks @JoeB for the response. As per the organisation's security practice, we would need to know the cache location. A solution that we could come up with was instead of using the SecretCache, we would be implementing out own cache mechanism and store it on an EC2 instance.  So far I am able to implement the LRU caching in python , but I am struggling to find  a way to store it in the EC2 instance (in-memory). Could you please provide a pointer as to how can I store it in EC2 in encrypted format (not plain text/string as these are sensitive informations), and how to rotate these values.TIA